# Apache Ignite : How to set client node's connection instance to 'NULL' up on server node down?

Tags: hadoop, caching, ignite, in-memory-database

In our use case we want to reuse the client's connection object, so, we haven't closed it. But once the server is restarted for some reason, my client node is still holding the older connection object(through which I cannot get access for my server Caches). So if it can be set to null after server down, we ask client node to start the connection again. So kindly guide us how to set client's connection object to null once server is down.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is `connection object` that you are referring to, but you can set `clientReconnectDisabled` to `true` on DiscoverySpi to make sure that client does not try to reconnect. When it gets disconnected, just create a new client and connect it anew.

Comment: Hi Alamar, can you guide us that how can we capture client disconnected event, so that we can create a new client.(Here in my case the client disconnection is due to server down) So the idea is, if I can capture that client disconnect event, I'll mark flag(like :isClientDisconnected) and  before fetching the data from Cache I'll check the flag and ask for client reconnectio(new client) based on flag value.

Comment: You can try and listen for `AFTER_NODE_STOP` lifecycle event.